# Gerrit LDAP configuration

Tags: java, ldap, gerrit

I'm trying to configure gerrit to user LDAP, but I'm having some problems with it.

I have the following:

**LDAP configuration:**

```
dc=test,dc=com
    cn=admin
    - cn=admins
      - cn=username
    ou=MyTeam
      -cn=developers
        -cn=myusername
```

and I've configured gerrit to use this:

```
[ldap]
    server = ldap://localhost
    username = myusername
    accountBase = ou=MyTeam,dc=test,dc=com
    groupBase = ou=MyTeam,dc=test,dc=com`
```

and gerrit doesn't allow me to log in with the following error

> `ERROR com.google.gerrit.server.auth.ldap.LdapRealm : Cannot query LDAP to authenticate user
>   javax.naming.InvalidNameException: [LDAP: error code 34 - invalid DN]`

Can somebody explain me how to set this properly?

Comment: Do you have to authenticate against the LDAP server?

Comment: Yes I am using ldap server for authentication

Answer (score 3):

This is what my configuration looks like. The username is required to be a user that is allowed to search in ldap. Maybe you need to use the fully qualified name. Sorry, my LDAP is also not so strong and I also had a hard time getting it to work but this configuration works...

```
[ldap]
  server = ldap://ldap
  username = cn=notadmin,dc=myteam,dc=test,dc=com
  accountBase = ou=users,dc=myteam,dc=test,dc=com
  groupBase = ou=gerrit,ou=groups,dc=myteam,dc=test,dc=com
  groupMemberPattern = (member=${dn})
  accountFullName = cn
```